# Typescript async generic function

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm new to TypeScript and I have an async function like the one below. Can someone explain what it does and where `resolve` comes from? I hope I'm providing enough information for this.

```
async function SendMessage<T extends WorkerResponse>(msg: { id: number }): Promise<T>
{
    const response = await new Promise<WorkerResponse>(resolve =>
    {
        waitingMessages.set(msg.id, resolve);
        worker.postMessage(msg);
    });

    return response as T;
}
```

When I hover the mouse over the variables I get these:

```
(parameter) resolve: (value: WorkerResponse | PromiseLike<WorkerResponse>) => void

const waitingMessages: Map<number, (response: WorkerResponse) => void>
```

Comment: This is a JavaScript question. Look up Promises.

Comment: `resolve` is a part of the Promise concept. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Probably author should start from even lower basics: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resolve` comes from the `Promise` constructor. The `Promise` constructor calls the function you give it (the *executor function*) with two arguments. When defining an executor function, we idiomatically name the parameters to receive those arguments `resolve` and `reject`:

- `resolve` - *Resolves* the promise (which may or may not *fulfill* it — here's [my blog post on Promise terminology](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/))
- `reject` - *Rejects* the promise

The purpose of the code in the executor function is to start whatever asynchronous process the promise will report on, and then (when that process concludes), either: 1) use `resolve` to fulfill the promise, 2) use `resolve` to *resolve* the promise *to* another promise, or 3) use `reject` to reject the promise.

The `async` function you've shown does this:

- Calls `new Promise`.

  - The `Promise` constructor calls the executor function passed to it synchronously, giving it access to `resolve` and `reject` functions. The one you've shown optimistically (and probably incorrectly) only uses a `resolve` parameter.
  - The executor code calls `waitingMessages.set(msg.id, resolve);`, which presumably sets up an eevn handler passing `resolve` as the handler implementation, and then `worker.postMessage(msg);` to send the message.
- The code `await`s the promise. (Which makes `SendMessage` return the promise it implicitly creates; it'll settle the promise it returns later.)
- At some point, presumably the event gets fired and `waitingMessages` calls `resolve`, which probably fulfills the promise with some value (a *fulfillment value*).
- Because the promise is fulfilled, the `await` is satisfied, and `response` gets assigned the fulfillment value of the promise that was `await`ed.
- `SendMessage`'s code returns that value, which fulfills the promise `SendMessage` implicitly returned, using the `response` value as the fulfillment value of that promise.

I've avoided going into too much detail above, but that's the gist.

None of this is specifically related to TypeScript, it's just how JavaScript promises work.

I suggest reading through [Using Promises on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) or any good Promise introductory tutorial or book.

Comment: FWIW, I cover promises in detail in Chapter 8 of my book [*JavaScript: The New Toys*](https://thenewtoys.dev), and cover `async`/`await` in detail in Chapter 9.

Comment: Thank you for this very clear explanation, I think now I understand what this piece of code does and the basics of the concept of promises! And also I will read the resources you mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

As you can see he is building a new Promise object , which takes as parameter resolve and reject .

In this case as you can see it's returning the resolve function this is as saying Promise.resolve() with some values inside of it . But you are resolving and it's returning this object

```js
{
       waitingMessages.set(msg.id, resolve);
       worker.`enter code here`postMessage(msg);
      });
```

question is not really related to typescript but to javascript promise concept and async await .

Answer (score 1):

What it does is that it creates a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which provides you with a resolve function that you can run to mark the promise as fulfilled. If you `await` the `SendMessage` function, the code execution will stop until the `resolve` function is run.

It seems to add a message ID to some form of messages queue, and then  send the message via a web worker. You can read more about web workers [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

```
const result = await SendMessage(yourMessage);
console.log('These console.logs will not be run until something in your code..');
console.log('..executes the resolve function that was being stored via waitingMessages.set');
```